# Submit multiple entries in database table through single object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, And stuck in this problem from last two days
I have a student and student_parent model they have a **one-to-many** relationship i want to **build database attribute through one object from form to datase**.

controller's method

```
def new
    @student = Student.new
    1.times{ @student.student_parents.build }
    .....
    .....
end
```

Create Method:-

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @student.save
            format.html { redirect_to Student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @student, status: :created, location: @student }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Model:-

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    include ErrorMessages

    belongs_to  :user
    has_many :student_parents

    attr_accessible :birth_date, :blood_group, :first_name, :gender, :last_name, :middle_name,
                  :school_name, :student_rollno, :email, :user_id, :student_parents_attributes

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_parents
end
```

form:-

```
<%= simple_form_for @student, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3">
    <%= f.label :first_name, :class => 'control-label',:required => true %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <%= f.label :middle_name, :class => 'control-label'%>
    <%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <%= f.label :last_name, :class => 'control-label',:required => true %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
</div> &nbsp;

<div class="control-group">
  <label  class = "control-label"> Email </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'text_field'  %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label  class = "control-label"> Birth Date <abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :birth_date, :class => 'text_field' ,'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>
  </div>
</div>

<% model_class = StudentParent %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h4> Parent  Information</h4>
  </div>

<%= f.fields_for :student_parents  do |student_parent| %>
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <!--<div class="span9">-->

       <h5> Father Name </h5>

       <div class="span3">
          <%= student_parent.label :first_name, :class => 'control-label',:required => true %>
          <%= student_parent.text_field :first_name %>
       </div>

       <div class="span3">
          <%= student_parent.label :middle_name, :class => 'control-label'%>
          <%= student_parent.text_field :middle_name %>
       </div>

       <div class="span3">
          <%= student_parent.label :last_name, :class => 'control-label',:required => true %>
          <%= student_parent.text_field :last_name %>
       </div>

  </div> &nbsp;

    <div class="row-fluid">

      <h5> Mother Name </h5>

      <div class="span3">
        <%= student_parent.label :first_name, :class => 'control-label',:required => true %>
        <%= student_parent.text_field :first_name %>
      </div>

      <div class="span3">
        <%= student_parent.label :middle_name, :class => 'control-label'%>
        <%= student_parent.text_field :middle_name %>
      </div>

      <div class="span3">
        <%= student_parent.label :last_name, :class => 'control-label',:required => true %>
        <%= student_parent.text_field :last_name %>
      </div>

    </div> &nbsp;

<% end %>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
              students_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
```

when submit it only build student information in **student table** and mother information in **student_parent** table. But it **miss the parent** information.

Comment: Can you post your create method and models?

Comment: did you define relationship, a student can have multiple parents..?

Comment: Check out railscasts `196` for multi model form.